# Finding the number of items in a group based on the number of combinations

Tags: combinations

I don’t really have much math knowledge beyond my high school calculus class that I took like 15 years ago. Can someone help me to find how to solve a problem like this?

I have 5 groups of items. There is an unknown number of items in each group. I know the number of combinations is 10000. How do I find the number of possible items in each group?

I can try to help with clarification if it doesn’t make sense. I’m totally lost on this.

Comment: Is a combination made up of exactly one item from each group?

Comment: Yes 1 item from each group

Comment: So in effect you have 5 unknowns $u,v,w,x,y$ and the number of combinations is $10000 = u\cdot v \cdot w \cdot x\cdot y$?

Comment: If this is more or less the question, I would look at the prime decomposition of $10000 = 2^45^4$